# taskcanceledexception a task was canceled

Tags: c#, exception, logging, httpclient, sentry

I am receiving error
taskcanceledexception a task was canceled without any inner exception details, and I am not receiving taskcanceled exception in Sentry. How can I see what the stack trace for this exception is or what changes I need to make to the code ?

Thanks

```
    private T CallDiffbotAndDeserialise<T>(string baseUrl, string pageUrl, int maxTags, int minimumTagConfidencePercentage)
    {
        var client = diffBotConnection.GetClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync($"?token={settings.DiffBotToken}&maxTags={maxTags}&tagConfidence={minimumTagConfidencePercentage / 100}&url={Uri.EscapeDataString(pageUrl)}&ts={DateTime.Now.ToSafeCacheString()}").Result;
            string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            T diffBotResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);

            return diffBotResponse;
        }
        catch (AggregateException e) // If the task is cancelled or times out
        {
            return default(T);
        };
    }
```

API connection:

```
public abstract class APIConnection : IDisposable
{
    protected HttpClient Client;
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected APIConnection() : this(3000) { }

    protected APIConnection(int timeOut)
    {
        Client = new HttpClient()
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeOut)
        };
    }

    public HttpClient GetClient() => Client;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Client.Dispose();
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the exception thrown, since you know it gets thrown you should be able to figure out where it comes from? By the way, catching an `AggregateException` will catch a lot more than `// If the task is cancelled or times out`

Comment: Sidenote: why are you using `.Result` instead of proper async/await?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `.Result` which always throws `AggregateException`.

That means you are not only catching `TaskCancelledException` or `OperationCancelledException`, you'll catch anything thrown by the two calls to `.Result`.

Since you are handling the exception and hiding the fact it ever happened (by catch and returning) Sentry won't know about it. If you want to send that event to Sentry, you'd need to call the Sentry client manually.

With [SharpRaven](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-csharp):

```
var ravenClient = new RavenClient("dsn"); // Initialize the client
ravenClient.CaptureEvent(new SentryEvent(exception));
```

With the [new SDK Sentry is developing](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/) (which is still a preview release):

```
// Initialize the SDK only once, at the start of the app
using (SentrySdk.Init("dsn"))  
{
    SentrySdk.AddBreadcrumb($"Starting a web request to: {baseUrl}");
    try
    {
       // make request
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        SentrySdk.CaptureException(exception);
    }
}
```

In this example I added a [breadcrumb](https://docs.sentry.io/learn/breadcrumbs/) which in case of an event (for example capturing an exception explicitly like above) is sent together with the event.

Also note that the new SDK automatically detects exceptions that go unhandled. That is not the case of your exemple since you are explicitly catching it.

I think it's important to mention that ideally you would avoid *blocking the thread* by calling `.Result` and instead would use `async/await`.

The `await` keyword unwraps the `Exception` from the faulted `Task`.
That means that your `catch` block could now catch `OperationCancelledException` instead. Any other error like a total failure to connect to the server would not go into your catch block and instead would bubble up the stack.